# Responsive Design for Large-Sized Phones

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm designing a website using media queries and have everything looking good on desktop and my iPad...but my phone is a different story. The pixel dimensions are 1024x768 because it is a newer smart phone, so it is trying to display it like my tablet. How can I use a media query to specify that my phone at 1024x768 should display differently than my iPad? Thanks for any help.

Here's what I've been working with to start:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
```

Comment: Can you post what your viewport meta tag looks like?

Comment: I have not use any viewports yet. Would the answer be in there?

Comment: Start with something like this to get you started: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">

Comment: @Lokase By disabling zooming, are you trying to make your users hate you?

Comment: @Cimmanon Its for a DARL (Device Agnostic Responsive Layout) solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Initial thoughts**

Some additional information on the exact layout problem on your phone would be helpful. Also, do make sure you are using the proper `<meta>` tag (as @Lokase suggested). A good run down can be found [here](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/quick-tip-dont-forget-the-viewport-meta-tag/).

**Two possible solutions**

1. Use`min-height` and `max-height` in combination with the
   `width` media queries you are already using to attempt to target
   your phone.
2. If that is not an option, you can use javascript to target your
   phone by attempting to detect the user agent, but this can be hit or
   miss.

**A word of Warning**

With all that said  **trying to design for specific viewports will lead to endless frustration**. A more time intensive you may need to step back and rethink your layout, and how you are using media queries. This can be a pain to implement, but you will thank yourself in the long run. Just consider the number of high resolution android phones in the market now, and how many are going to be shipping soon.